# Algolia React Instantsearch - react native - 'query' search parameter not working

Tags: react-native, algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm using the react-instantsearch module on a React Native app. I'm using it as a controlled component, passing in a `searchState` like so:

```
  <InstantSearch
    appId='something'
    apiKey='somethingElse'
    indexName='index'
    searchState={this.props.algoliaSearchState}
  >
```

When I change the category (`hierarchicalMenu`) or location (`aroundLatLng`), this works fine, but when I change the `query` it has no effect on the hits that I get.

I can see that the `query` is being passed in (both by logging, and in react-native devtools: 
[image: screenshot from devtools]

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a refinement to be applied, it needs to be present inside the search state and have a corresponding widget mounted.

For `hierarchicalMenu` it's `HierarchicalMenu`, for `aroundLatLng` it's `Configure` and for `query` it's `SearchBox`.

If you don't want any rendering for a widget just create a [VirtualWidget](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/guide/Virtual_widgets.html). But for its refinement to be applied, it should be mounted.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I added a virtual SearchBox and it worked.